# Visual Studio 2019 Community toolbox has no webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

[My Visual Studio toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s7x9.png)

I have a WinForms app, when I design a form, the toolbox shows no webbrowser control. The framework is .NET 5.0. I use Visual Studio 2019 Community latest version v16.8.6, as shown in the screenshot.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried just seeing if you can instantiate one in your code somewhere, its definitely there.

Comment: @Codexer Yes, I can instantiate webbrowser using code, but i can not find it in toolbox

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216269/how-to-create-a-web-browser-with-visual-studio-201.html

Answer (score 2):

The WebBrowser control is outdated and struggles to render most modern websites proprely. I would recommend using WebView2 instead which is based on Chromium Edge https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Answer (score 1):

I have VS 2022 and .NET 6.0 and it is not in the toolbox there either. I was able to add it by editing the MyForm.Designer.cs file. There are 4 sections of the file that I added code to.
this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

```
        // 
        // webBrowser1
        // 
        this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1064, 24);
        this.webBrowser1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 3, 5, 3);
        this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 27);
        this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
        this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(405, 506);
        this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 27;
```

this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);

private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;

Answer (score 0):

super ...works for me

this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

```
    // 
    // webBrowser1
    // 
    this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1064, 24);
    this.webBrowser1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 3, 5, 3);
    this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 27);
    this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
    this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(405, 506);
    this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 27;
```

this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);

private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).